# Paypal IPN working in IPN simulator but fail in sandbox environment

Tags: paypal-ipn

It was very weird. I set the IPN URL for my sandbox accounts and my server was able to receive the notifications POST from Paypal sandbox yesterday. But today I checked both logs from application and web server, no IPN received from PayPal sandbox even after I successfully completed the transactions like other days.

I logged into the sandbox site to check if there was any IPN created, the IPNs were there but the status showed retrying. I double checked the web server logs, nothing from Paypal except the one sent from the simulator.

I was very sure the IPN URL was correct because I didn't change at all. I tried to use IPN simulator from the PayPal developer site and it was working, I could receive notifications from the simulator. But that's not what I want! Anything wrong with PayPal sandbox IPN recently? Please Help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same problem with test environment here, yesterday all went fine, today no IPN requests at all

paypal sandbox status is empty too https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=productIPN

Comment: All of sudden I received all the IPNs nearly 4 hours after those requests were sent. It is NOT "INSTANT" Payment Notification. Spending 3 hours looking for errors....

Comment: It's working again, propably only overload issues on environment machines